# Configuring Apache Tomcat to run PHP

Tags: linux, apache

I would like to start out by apologizing. I have very little knowledge in the areas of Linux and Servers. I have been asked at work to set up a Linux box running Apache Tomcat. The Server needs to be enabled to allow websockets. I managed to get Debian installed. During the installation it gave me the option to make it a web server, which I did. There are now some different folders and files that are named "apache" in the files system, so my guess is that I am in fact running Apache, but to be honest I'm not 100% sure, and if it is, I don't know if its Tomcat. I fumbled around a bit and figured out the IP address of the computer I installed on and tried going to that IP from another computer in the network and it worked. I was able to see the html file that I put in the /var/www folder on the host machine. I then went out and found a nice piece of code, someone was kind enough to share, that is suppose to test websockets capability but I cant seem to get it working. My thinking is that my server isn't allowing PHP to run. I came to this conclusion by testing. I took a web page from my other server, its written in PHP, that when opened will send a text to my phone. Its just a small piece of code that I used for testing. When I tried running it from the Linux server it wont run, meaning it wont send the text to my phone. So here I am. I realize I'm asking for a simple solution to a complex problem, but I'm under the gun so to speak. I have about a week to get this going, so I just don't have the time to really immerse my self in this stuff the way I would like to. My question in its simplest form is"How do I configure my server to run PHP?" Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you all for your time and patience.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a simple PHP script like `echo 'Hello World';`??

If not then try, if it works then your PHP is up, but sockets are just not configured to use.

If it doesn't work then install Ubuntu, a simple newbie friendly interface for Linux, and then install LAMP, [here its how to do it](http://www.lamphowto.com/).
And don't panic.